# Unable to log in

Tags: password, password-recovery

Although I've set up a username and password when I was installing Ubuntu 13.04, when I type in my password it says it's incorrect although language is checked and my password's correct. What's wrong?

Comment: All lower case used still no result.

Answer (score 0):

If You don't want to reinstall your os, then you can boot from a live CD an generate passwd hash, and replace the line in /etc/shadow

The structure of the file is:

[image]

the second field is the password hash.