# Unable able to log in

Tags: boot

Please, I can't log into my Ubuntu account. I have tried logging in using the right password. But can gain access to my account.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: It was already asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/306015/unable-to-log-in)

Answer (score 0):

if you really are using the right password maybe your keyboard isn't using the right layout.
Could be that you are typing on a QWERTZ or AZERTY Layout but your system is interpreting it as a QWERTY. Try switching Letters Y and Z if u r on QWERTZ Keyboard and A and Q on a AZERTY